# How can I install Mosquitto on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, apt

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I am struggling with installing Mosquitto.
It seems to be caused by a bad `mosquitto-jessie.list` file:

```
deb https://repo.mosquitto.org/debian jessie main
```

It could not find any updates (it gives a 404 error all the time).
Could someone send a valid `mosquitto-jessie.list` with its contents?
(I have tried to download it again with wget)

I am getting hints to install from [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Installing-MQTT-BrokerMosquitto-on-Raspberry-Pi/).

It seems also that this is duplicated with this topic
(https://community.home-assistant.io/t/help-installing-mosquitto/32741/8)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. If you work out a solution based from that new link you have included, feel free to post an answer yourself.

Comment: Mosquitto v1.4.10 is available in the Raspbian Stretch repositories (by just running `sudo apt install mosquitto` without editing any configuration). Would that be acceptable or do you specifically need a newer version?

Comment: I am opened to any version of mosquitto, but as I run this exact command I get bunch of Ign/errors that http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages
nor http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages   cannot be found. This outupt I get without any modification, only apt-get install command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had proxy set up which redirecting gzipped package somewhere else.

Delete the file

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy
```

Reboot the system